# can we create our own System class in java , if yes then how?

Tags: java

```
public void MySystem class{
    //here  MySystem is my own System class in place of System class which available in java.lang package //
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it? Do you want to create a class that dose every thing the `System` class dose? Or just want to create a new class named by `System`?

Comment: You can create any class you like.  What specifically is stopping you?  (Other than the syntax errors in your example... You might want to start with a Java tutorial.)

Comment: `void` is not applicable to class definitions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just write the necessary code and you're good to go. It's the same as with any other class.